# apply / trigger not passing correct parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, publish-subscribe

I've run into a strange problem with my jQuery code. I have a setup [as follows](http://pastebin.com/CbGndMDU):

```
(function($) {
    var o = $({});

    $.subscribe = function() { o.on.apply(o, arguments); };
    $.publish = function() { o.trigger.apply(o, arguments); };
}(jQuery));

(function($) {

    var CarrierView = {
        subscriptions: function() {
            $.subscribe( 'reporting.carrier.model.changed', this.renderModel );
        },
        renderModel: function( e, data ) {
            var self = CarrierView;
        }
    };

    var CarrierModel = {
        subscriptions: function() {
            $.subscribe( 'reporting.carrier.model.update', this.updateModel );
        },
        updateModel: function( value ) {
            $.getJSON('carriers', function( data ) {
                $.publish( 'reporting.carrier.model.changed', data );
            });
        }
    };

    window.CarrierView = CarrierView.init();
    window.CarrierModel = CarrierModel.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Running a very basic pub/sub. My issue is the following:

A click event triggers the `CarrierModel.updateModel` method, which calls `$.getJSON`. The `data` returned is an `Array[99]`, which is then `publish`ed. When `CarrierView.renderModel` is called, the `data` there is the first element of the `Array[99]`, an `Array[5]`. What am I doing incorrectly? How do I pass the whole set of `data` to the View?

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/12151913/1296553

Comment: Interesting. Seems jQuery's `trigger` doesn't allow passing arrays. Any idea why this is? A quick google search hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: I really don't know why. Check see this fiddle it may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/wUCsc/